# Laplace transform of $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}dt$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, laplace-transform, laplacian, laplace-method

Laplace transform of $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}dt$.

So far I've calculated that $\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}$ transformed equals $\frac{1}{8}(\ln((s+1)^2+4)-2\ln(s+1))$. 
My question is what should I do with integral $\int_{0}^\infty$ ?

Comment: You want the Laplace transform of the integral $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}dt$ or the expression $\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}$? The integral is just a constant, so it corresponds to Laplace transform of a $1$ times that constant. If you're interested in Laplace transform of the expression  $\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}$, then this is another story.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I want to transform that whole expression(with integral). I just thought that i should first transform  $\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2t}{t}$ , and then integrate it from 0 to inf

Comment: @user3104311: that procedure computes $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2(t)}{t^{\color{red}{2}}}\,dt.$$ In your case, you may compute the Laplace transform of $e^{-t}\sin^2(t)$ and integrate it over $\mathbb{R}^+$: that gives $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2(t)}{t}\,dt$.

Comment: *"To transform the whole expression (with integral)"* has little sense since you would compute the Laplace transform of a constant.

Answer (score 1):

My free interpretation is: *how to use the Laplace transform to compute the integral*
$$ I=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}\sin^2(t)}{t}\,dt $$
? Well, since:
$$\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-t}\sin^2(t)\right)=\frac{2}{(1+s)(5+2s+s^2)}\tag{1}$$
[we have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis):
$$ I = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(1+s)(5+2s+s^2)}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{4+e^{2u}}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dv}{4+e^v}\tag{2} $$
or:
$$ I = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dw}{w(4+w)}=\color{red}{\frac{\log 5}{4}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Yeah but $\frac{f(t)}{t}$ transforms to  $\int_{s}^\infty F(s)ds$  so I would apply that rule to $\frac{2}{(1+s)(5+2s+s^2)}\tag{1}$, and then integrate it from 0 to infinity. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3104311: I used the identity $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}(\mathcal{L} f)(s)\,ds.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-t}\sin^{2}\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\
\overbrace{{1 - \cos\pars{2t} \over 2}}^{\ds{=\ \sin^{2}\pars{2t}}}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-tx}\,\dd x}^{\ds{=\ {1 \over t}}}\
\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\bracks{\expo{-\pars{x + 1}t} - \expo{-\pars{x + 1 + 2\ic}t}}\,\dd t\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\half\,\Re\int_{0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over x + 1} - {1 \over x + 1 + 2\ic}}\,\dd x =
\left.\half\,\Re\ln\pars{x + 1 \over x + 1 + 2\ic}\right\vert_{\ x\ =\ 0}^{\ x\ \to\ \infty}
\\[3mm] & =
\half\,\Re\ln\pars{1 + 2\ic} =
\half\,\ln\pars{\root{1^{2} + 2^{2}}} =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{5}}
\end{align}